# Deploying standalone application to Micro Cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

This [post](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/post/13481011624/cloud-foundry-improves-support-for-background-processing) demonstrates how to deploy standalone applications to CloudFoundry.

However, I'm not able to do it with Micro CloudFoundry 1.2. How do I add the standalone plugin to the list of frameworks?

```
>vmc runtimes

+--------+-------------+-----------+
| Name   | Description | Version   |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| java   | Java 6      | 1.6       |
| ruby18 | Ruby 1.8    | 1.8.7     |
| ruby19 | Ruby 1.9    | 1.9.2p180 |
| node   | Node.js     | 0.4.12    |
| node06 | Node.js     | 0.6.8     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+


>vmc frameworks

+----------+
| Name     |
+----------+
| spring   |
| java_web |
| sinatra  |
| grails   |
| node     |
| lift     |
| rails3   |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micro Cloud Foundry 1.2 is based on an older version of the Cloud Foundry source code, which does not support standalone apps. You'll need to wait for a new release of Micro Cloud Foundry to include the newest features.

In the meantime, you could set up a local Ubuntu VM and install the latest Cloud Foundry source at http://www.cloudfoundry.org/, or just use CloudFoundry.com.